# Why wasn't intellij idea exploded war equal to the mvn package output war?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module maven java project.

When I import from the pom, idea produces war artifact automatically. And I

used the shaded plugin for fat jar in one of the module. The mvn packaged phase

output war contained the fat jar. But the jar in idea produced war is not

a fat jar. Why?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK idea is not completely repeating build configuration of maven. Usually it's importing basic maven configuration to create modules and artifacts. But of course it's not capable of repeating all plugins used in maven.

So you have in parallel two build configurations:

- maven
- intelliJ

You can try to configure manually intelliJ build artifact in project settings, to reflect what you need

Comment: I dont know how to config artifact based on maven build conf. Do I have to add artifact of every module, and then put the artifact int the exploded war lib?

Comment: go to `Project structure` -> `Artifacts`

Comment: I know  this, but how can I add the artifact based on maven conf.

Comment: I guess there is no way if you are using this shade plugin